# Memory leak when creating cycled object in PHP7 extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension

The following is the test function I created (for PHP 7.1).

```
PHP_FUNCTION(tsc_test3)
{
    zend_string *cnA;
    zend_class_entry *ceA;

    // $ret = new ClsA();
    cnA = zend_string_init("ClsA", 4, 0);
    ceA = zend_fetch_class(cnA, ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_DEFAULT);
    zend_string_release(cnA);
    object_init_ex(return_value, ceA);

    // $ret->propA = $ret;
    zval objA;
    ZVAL_COPY(&objA, return_value);
    zend_update_property(ceA, return_value, "propA", 5, &objA);
    zval_ptr_dtor(&objA);

    return;
}
```

As suggested in the comment, it returns a cycled object of `ClsA`.
The following is the test PHP program for the function.

```php
<?php
class ClsA {
    public $propA = 1;
}

$x = tsc_test3();

echo "DUMP1 ----\n";
var_dump($x);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo "Memory usage: ". memory_get_usage(). "\n";
    $x = tsc_test3();
}

echo "DUMP2 ----\n";
var_dump($x);

$x->propA = null;

echo "DUMP3 ----\n";
var_dump($x);
```

Here is the output of the PHP code.

```
DUMP1 ----
object(ClsA)#1 (1) {
  ["propA"]=>
  *RECURSION*
}
Memory usage: 351336
Memory usage: 351392
Memory usage: 351448
Memory usage: 351504
Memory usage: 351560
Memory usage: 351616
Memory usage: 351672
Memory usage: 351728
Memory usage: 351784
Memory usage: 351840
DUMP2 ----
object(ClsA)#11 (1) {
  ["propA"]=>
  *RECURSION*
}
DUMP3 ----
object(ClsA)#11 (1) {
  ["propA"]=>
  NULL
}
```

The `var_dump()` result looks fine, but memory usage constantly increases.

When I use `ZVAL_COPY_VALUE` instead of `ZVAL_COPY`, the memory usage doesn't increase, but it produces a weird output in DUMP3.

```
DUMP3 ----
*RECURSION*
```

May be the function returns a corrupted object.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong in the extension function?

<s>Edit1: Just after posting the question I noticed `memory_get_usage(true)` doesn't increase. Is this the mistake I made?</s>

Edit2: The following PHP program (pure PHP, no extension) shows increasing memory usage. Is this a PHP bug or am I misunderstanding something? I'm using PHP 7.1.28.

```php
<?php
class ClsA {
    public $propA = 1;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo "Memory usage: ". memory_get_usage(). "\n";
    $x = new ClsA();
    $x->propA = $x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the PHP garbage collector doesn't always reclaim the memory used by your object (a `ClsA` instance) at the *exact* moment you assign your reference (`$x`) to another object. PHP uses ref counting and garbage collection altogether.

If you force a garbage collection on each loop, you will see that your memory footprint will remain the same :

```
<?php
class ClsA {
    public $propA = 1;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    gc_collect_cycles();
    echo "Memory usage: ". memory_get_usage(). "\n";
    $x = new ClsA();
    $x->propA = $x;
}
```

Output :

```
$ php test.php
Memory usage: 396296 <-- before the first ClsA allocation
Memory usage: 396384
Memory usage: 396384
Memory usage: 396384
Memory usage: 396384
Memory usage: 396384
Memory usage: 396384
Memory usage: 396384
Memory usage: 396384
Memory usage: 396384
```

More (technical) info here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php

Comment: I makes perfect sense. With `gc_collect_cycles()`, I confirmed my PHP extension doesn't leak memory. Thank you.